# How do I use RegEx to leave numbers and math operators inside of parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript and RegEx, how I can start with something like this...

```
((5 dogs + 2 cats) * $3.00 per animal) + $20 flat fee
```

...and end up with just the math operators (allowing for both x and * for multiplication), dollar signs, decimal points, spaces and numbers...

```
(5 + 2) * $3.00) + $20
```

Ideally, there would be two levels of nesting max; but if that's not possible, one level would also be useful.

Comment: "...with something like this..." is problematic. You are asking for a solution to a class of problems that you have only suggestively defined by giving a single example. For example, can there be any number of levels of nested parentheses?

Comment: @Cary: Gotcha. Ideally, two levels of nesting max, but one level would also be useful. Appended info to original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a string replace using a regular expression matching only symbols different from the allowed characters: `+-*/[0-9].$()` to be replaced with empty string.

Here's a demo:

```js
const formula = "((5 dogs + 2 cats) * $3.00 per animal) + $20 flat fee";
const result = formula.replace(/[^-+*\/()\d.$]/img, "");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: good point.. I didn't notice the problem before. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out.